# Is it possible to access freeform programatically?

Tags: ios

I'd like to be able create/read boards in the new app freeform which is included with iPadOS and iOS 16.2 for collaboration.

Is this API provided by Apple or a third party tool?

Comment: Just to add, searching is not helping. Maybe because it's just recently released.

Comment: Great question. Time will tell how it works or if a web app is provided like much of iCloud once the first few years of an app (like pages and numbers ) exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Freeform app does not provide an AppleScript dictionary, nor any Siri Shortcuts.
Therefore the only programatic control is through UI scripting:

- [Automating the User Interface - Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html)

For example, to create a new board from the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) using [applescript](/questions/tagged/applescript) UI scripting:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Freeform" to activate' \
    -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Freeform" to click menu item "New Board" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1'
```

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but marking it correct. Thanks.